# What is the CVE-2014-6271 bash vulnerability (Shellshock) and how do I fix it?

Tags: bash, security, shellshock

Recently, there have been news going around regarding "CVE-2014-6271" (See [USN-2362-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2362-1/)), which is a vulnerability in Bash. How do I know if I am affected by this, how can I fix it, and why should I care?

This is designed as a canonical answer for this vulnerability, due to its scope and severity.

Comment: "how do I fix it?" -> **just run your upgrade manager!** Really, Ubuntu releases security updates, there's a dedicated security team. *Please don't post answers about building Bash from source!*; it's needlessly complicated and harder to maintain your system in the future.

Comment: Plus, also the additional CVE for the incomplete fix. [CVE-2014-7169](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-7169.html)

Comment: Please _do_ post answers about building from source.  Whether they should or not, some people have ancient Ubuntu servers, and building from source may be their only option.

Comment: I notice that dash is also vulnerable!  dash is the default shell /bin/sh used by cgi etc.  I'm not sure if dash is based on dash but it's has the same exploit.

Comment: @matth can you show a source, article, or demo to show that it is actually vulnerable? I've seen many articles indicating the contrary.

Comment: I ran the same check and it came up as vulnerable.  let me check again.

Comment: Ok so the issue is, that after the function definition it should stop parsing.  But bash continues executing arbitrary commands if vulnerable.  The test is this:  
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"  outputs "vulnerable this is a test" on my copy of dash.  Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: oops, sorry I just realised I put bash instead of dash in the test.  Never mind it's fine.

Comment: Read: [oss-sec: Re: CVE-2014-6271: remote code execution through bash](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/771). Bash bug still hasn't been fixed

Comment: @blade19899 the new CVE has been fixed and I have already updated my answer. I'll update the question to use the better known term shellshock.

Comment: Note: If you use ANYTHING besides the primary update servers (Software & Updates -> Ubuntu Software -> Download From: "Server for [country]" OR "Main Server") you risk my problem.  I had a faster server (discovered using the "Select Best Server" button), but one that apparently never received the FIRST update, much less the subsequent ones.

Comment: I used this website and ran the bash script (which just runs a set of vulnerability checks on your shell). Works like a charm. https://shellshocker.net/   To fix, just update your bash to the latest.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

### What is Bash?

Bash is the default interactive shell in Ubuntu. When you are interfacing with the terminal (either through the terminal emulator, over a tty, or ssh), you are generally typing commands that `bash` will read, and execute. Even if you do not use the terminal at all, you still have Bash.

On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is not bash (it is dash). Only bash is affected by this vulnerability.

### How does the exploit affect me?

Bash and the OS keep track of a set of *environment variables* that describe the current logged-on user, where to look for programs on the hard disk, and other such functions. By crafting an environment variable with a specific structure, an attacker might be able to execute code next time Bash starts.

The attacker can set that environment variable multiple ways:

- Remotely connect to a service such as SSH with a specific setup such as git over ssh. As Mitre warns, the use of the sshd `ForceCommand` option is an attack vector. Accounts whose shell isn't bash aren't affected.
- Tricking you into setting the environment variable.
- Causing another program to set an environment variable to have that crafted value. For example, you might have a webserver and script that needs to set an environment variable with specific user content. Even if that script creates its own, and doesn't touch other environment variables, it's enough. *A single environment variable with any name and a crafted value is enough for the exploit to succeed*.
- Other  ways I have not mentioned here.

Once they set this variable, the next time `bash` opens for *any* reason, your attacker's code will be run. This is especially fearsome with `sudo -s`, as it spawns bash as the super-user (an administrative user rule that has **full** control over your computer's data and programs). Even if you only start bash as a standard user, that user's files can be deleted.

It is important to note that even if you do not use bash yourself, many programs will spawn bash by themselves as part of their operation. Even in this case, you are vulnerable. However, Ubuntu's `/bin/sh` is not bash, so only programs that explicitly invoke bash and not the default scripting shell are affected.

According to Mitre:

> vectors involving the ForceCommand feature in OpenSSH sshd, the mod_cgi and mod_cgid modules in the Apache HTTP Server, scripts executed by unspecified DHCP clients, and other situations in which setting the environment occurs across a privilege boundary from Bash execution.

### Am I vulnerable?

Use dpkg to check your installed package version:

```
dpkg -s bash | grep Version
```

This will look up info on your `bash` package, and filter the output to only show you the version. The fixed versions are [`4.3-7ubuntu1.4`](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2364-1/), `4.2-2ubuntu2.5`, and `4.1-2ubuntu3.4`.

For example, I see:

```
wlan1-loopback% dpkg -s bash | grep Version
Version: 4.3-7ubuntu1.4
```

and can determine that I am not vulnerable.

### How do I update?

The standard update manager will offer you this update. This is a prime example of how security updates are important, no matter what OS you use or how well-maintained it is.

The [USN Bulletin](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2362-1/) states that new versions have been released for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, 12.04 Precise Pangolin, and 10.04 Lucid Lynx. If you are not on one of these LTS versions, but are on a reasonably-recent version, you'll most likely be able to find a patched package.

First, check if you

If you are vulnerable, you should first grab the newest package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bash
```

The first command makes sure that you have the newest package list that includes the fixed version, and the second command installs the newest (fixed) version of bash.

While the bug only appears to come into play when bash is spawned, it's still a good idea to reboot immediately if feasible.

Comment: Sorry, **you are vulnerable**. The original patch does not fix the whole problem. See https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-7169 AFAIAA, there is currently _no_ publicly available fix. See e.g. http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/pkg/bash.html

Comment: Care to explain this: "Remotely connect to a service such as SSH, and **try to log in**."? "try" as in one does not have to achieve a valid ssh login?

Comment: @Rinzwind updated.

Comment: @hexafraction What should I do if i still have a box with Ubuntu 12.10? As this bug is very severe, can we expect Ubuntu to still provide a patched package for no longer supported releases?

Comment: @Michael as long as you have a backport repository enabled in software sources you should get a fixed version that addresses the first CVE. The second that was reported has not had a fix released yet.

Comment: @hexafraction Thanks. I've done that and also updated the URLs in my `sources.list` to point to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/. Still I don't get any updates for bash. So the fix has probably not been backported yet.

Comment: @hexafraction Where do you read that 12.10 receives an update for this? I don't think so, **12.10, 13.04, 13.10 are very much End-of-Life**! And also, backport repositories are **not used for security updates**.

Comment: @hexafraction No, they don't! That's the whole point of being End-of-Life: no support at all anymore.

Comment: @hexafraction do mention the CVE due to the incomplete fix in these patches (given in Mormegil's comment). This answer is incomplete without it. -1 until then.

Comment: @Rinzwind The statement about ssh is invalid I think, ssh wont touch bash without first going through authentication, so the vector only exists for people who can authenticate. More info [here](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/laws-of-vulnerabilities/2014/09/24/bash-shellshock-vulnerability)

Comment: @hexafraction I'm not sure how you get from `ForceCommand` to "By crafting a specific login name or hostname". At the very least you should state that user must be able to authenticate. Your stated conditions might be necessary but is not sufficient.

Comment: I don't like it when unexplained code is published as `env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'echo hello'`. Can you explain what exactly this does? If not, I am not going to run it. It's like people shouting one should run `rm -r ~` and that sort of stuff.

Comment: @don.joey it simply sets the environment variable called x to the value '() { :;}; echo vulnerable'. It then invokes bash asking it to echo back the word hello. The value of x that is set is a function definition that should do nothing. However, it is crafted to try to run 'echo vulnerable' at parsing of environment at bash start-up, which just prints vulnerable to standard out.

Comment: Dash is doing the same thing for me.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl If you're on Ubuntu 12.10, you can download the 12.04 version of bash from http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/bash and install it manually.

Comment: Looks like 4.3-7ubuntu1.2 and other updates are out : https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages

Comment: @daveshaw I would recommend creating a separate answer about the security-proposed ppa.

Comment: Worked for me on my crufty old 12.04 machine.

Comment: Fix for CVE-2014-7169 is available in the update manager (for me).

Comment: I am on Ubutnu 13.10 (and I do not want to update my distribution). My bash version is  4.2-5ubuntu3 It is not in the list of fixed versions given above. What can I do??

Comment: @lpdbw I'm not able to give instructions on releases other that the ones listed on the usn as I have no way of finding a good version and verifying that it is indeed actually secure.

Comment: You mention 4.1-2ubuntu3.1 as safe, but 4.1-2ubuntu3.4 has been released fixing CVE-2014-7186 and CVE-2014-7187. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/4.1-2ubuntu3.4

Answer (score 27):

Stole this off of [cft over at Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8364385). If you have trouble with your repos like me(Odroid-XU), then this should work nicely if you want to patch/build from source.

```
TMPDIR=/tmp/bash-src
mkdir $TMPDIR
cd $TMPDIR
#download bash
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3.tar.gz
#download all patches
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 999); do 
  wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/bash43-$i
  if [[ $? -ne "0" ]]; then
    MAX=$(expr $i - 1)
    break;
  fi
done
tar zxf bash-4.3.tar.gz 
cd bash-4.3
#apply all patches
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 $MAX);do
  echo apply patch bash43-$i
  patch -p0 < ../bash43-$i
done
#build and install
./configure && make
sudo make install
cd ../..
rm -r $TMPDIR
```

Then run:

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

And if you get:

```
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
this is a test
```

Then you're all good!

---

**WARNING:** make install will install bash in `/usr/local/bin`, so `/bin/bash` is not modified and can be invoked from curl !!

Comment: Here's how to build bash 3.2 with the patch on debian lenny: https://gist.github.com/mattwhite/86de50d30134129e44ef

Comment: -1. No need to build from source. Ubuntu has a security patch in the repositories. If you have "troubles with your repo", fix that instead. You'll likely vulnerable in many more ways if you don't receive security upgrades!

Comment: @gertvdijk you are right, but not everybody uses ubuntu...

Comment: @Matt White Thank you! You just saved me a couple of hours :)

Comment: @FlorianFida This is AskUbuntu! Everybody on this site is expected to post answers in the scope of using Ubuntu.

Comment: @gertvdijk, as i said, you are right, its kind of off-topic here. But live is not that strict. many users of the debian family are looking for a fix right now... that's how i found this page. And there might be situations where this kind of fix is appropriate (custom bash build ?).

Comment: Hey lazy sysadmins : https://plus.google.com/u/0/109217393200753135791/posts/hc5bvYMnqV3

Comment: @gertvdijk Am I just missing it or is there no package available for 12.10? I've added backports to my sources but still no update of bash. If this is the case, then this proposal here might be the only way to fix this issue for non-LTS releases.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl 12.10 is End-of-Life. It does not receive any security updates anymore since a long time already. Upgrade!!!

Comment: +1 It worked like a charm for Ubuntu 12.10. You are a lifesaver

Comment: wouldn't be a better solution to [Install only bash from trusty on old distributions by a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/q/529957)

Comment: I edited the question so it [Gets all files in the directory listing of the path server](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159626). Also related: [How do I patch the shellshock vulnerability on an obsolete Ubuntu system that I can't upgrade?](http://superuser.com/a/816807)

Answer (score 9):

Note: The Security Patch for CVE-2014-7169 has been released as a standard security update. There is no need to add additional ppa's to receive this patch. Only the following is needed.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To ensure you have patched bash correctly, run the following command

```
dpkg -s bash | grep Version
```

If you are on 14.04 LTS, you should see an output of:

```
Version: 4.3-7ubuntu1.4
```

If you are on 12.04 LTS, your output should be:

```
 Version: 4.2-2ubuntu2.5
```

Comment: This was correct, but an official patch has now been made available, so the security update has been released. Consequently these steps are no longer necessary.

Comment: This is correct. I will edit the above post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 11.04: use below steps (it worked for me)

```
cd ~/
mkdir bash
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3.tar.gz
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 0 25); do wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/bash43-$i; done
```

if it is not downloaded required patche then install ftp package

```
apt-get install ftp
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 0 25); do wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/bash43-$i; done
tar zxvf bash-4.3.tar.gz
cd bash-4.3
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 0 25);do patch -p0 < ../bash43-$i; done
./configure && make && make install
apt-get install build-essential
./configure && make && make install
```

To see if the patch was applied:

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Natty 11.04, which is EOL (and I have updated /etc/apt/sources.list to use old-releases.ubuntu.com), so I have to build from source. I wanted to build a .deb, so at least the package manage is "aware" the bash version is not the default one. I am not 100% succesful - however, the package is registered as "newer" and the `bash` binary ends up fixed, so here is what I did:

```
apt-get source bash
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/drj11/e85ca2d7503f28ebfde8/raw/31bd53ed2e47b220d3c728f5440758e0f76769de/gistfile1.c -O bash_CVE-2014-6271.patch
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/drj11/239e04c686f0886253fa/raw/046e697da6d4491c3b733b0207811c55ceb9d927/gistfile1.c -O bash_CVE-2014-6271_plus.patch
cd bash-4.2/
```

Now, in the (sub)directory `bash-4.2/`, there is: a file `bash-4.2.tar.xz`, which needs to be unpacked to get to the `bash` source; and a subdirectory called `debian`.

I made the following changes to avoid dependencies on `texlive`: in `bash-4.2/debian/control`:

```
Source: bash
...
Build-Depends: autoconf, autotools-dev, patch, bison, libncurses5-dev,
# texinfo, debhelper (>= 5), texi2html, locales, gettext, sharutils, time, xz-ut
ils
 debhelper (>= 5), locales, gettext, sharutils, time, xz-utils
# Build-Depends-Indep: texlive-latex-base, ghostscript
Build-Depends-Indep: ghostscript
```

... and in `bash-4.2/debian/rules`:

```
binary-doc: bash-install #bash-doc-build
        dh_testdir
        dh_testroot
        mkdir -p $(d_doc)/usr/share/doc/$(p)
        dh_installdocs -p$(p_doc) 
ifeq ($(with_gfdl),yes)
        #cp -p build-bash/doc/bashref.pdf $(d_doc)/usr/share/doc/$(p)/.
        #dh_link -p$(p_doc) \
        #    /usr/share/doc/$(p)/bashref.pdf /usr/share/doc/$(p_doc)/bashref.pdf
else
        rm -f $(d_doc)/usr/share/doc-base/bashref
endif
        rm -f $(d_doc)/usr/share/info/dir*
        #cp -p build-bash/doc/bash.html build-bash/doc/bash.pdf \
        #    $(d_doc)/usr/share/doc/$(p)/
        #dh_link -p$(p_doc) \
        #    /usr/share/doc/$(p)/bash.html /usr/share/doc/$(p_doc)/bash.html \
        #    /usr/share/doc/$(p)/bash.pdf /usr/share/doc/$(p_doc)/bash.pdf
        dh_installchangelogs -p$(p_doc) bash/CWRU/changelog
        ...
```

To change the version, in this `bash-4.2/` directory, do:

```
bash-4.2$ dch --local patchCVE
```

... and fill in the notes in the changelog when asked. This will ensure that the .deb (and related metadata) is called (in my case) `bash_4.2-0ubuntu3patchCVE1_i386.deb`.

Then you can try building with `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` or `debuild` command. Note - either of these will re-unpack the source from the zip - thus overriding any patches you may have had! Still, run one of these once so the source is unpacked and built (note `debuild` may still fail in the end due to texlive, but it should unpack and build the source).

Then, apply the patches; note you should use `-p1` here, because currently you're in the `bash-4.2/` directory:

```
bash-4.2$ patch -p1 < ../bash_CVE-2014-6271.patch 
bash-4.2$ patch -p1 < ../bash_CVE-2014-6271_plus.patch
```

Then rebuild patched version by running:

```
bash-4.2$ fakeroot debian/rules build
```

This would rebuild the executable; to test it:

```
bash-4.2$ env VAR='() { :;}; echo Bash is vulnerable!' ./build-bash/bash -c "echo Bash Test"
```

To build the .deb files, run:

```
bash-4.2$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

This will save the .deb files in the parent directory; to list their contents:

```
bash-4.2$ dpkg -c ../bash_4.2-0ubuntu3patchCVE1_i386.deb
```

To install the .deb:

```
bash-4.2$ sudo dpkg -i ../bash_4.2-0ubuntu3patchCVE1_i386.deb
```

However, for some reason, this .deb contains an unpatched binary (?!), so I had to additionally do:

```
bash-4.2$ sudo cp bash-4.2/build-bash/bash /bin/
```

... and after that, the test started passing correctly for me:

```
$ env VAR='() { :;}; echo Bash is!' bash -c "echo Bash Test"
bash: warning: VAR: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `VAR'
Bash Test
```

Comment: Question: The Original Question states 1 possible attack vector as "scripts executed by unspecified DHCP clients". What does this mean? Does this mean that Ubuntu's /sbin/dhclient <-- is vulnerable?

Comment: I think maybe the unspecified clients means, that the Ubuntu has a infected /sbin/dhclient, which then runs commands which lead to the bash script launching shellshock. Is that what DHCP Clients are vulnerable to shellshock? (Hope that makes sense, see my above message from Oct. 10)