# How do I patch Ubuntu 14.04 for shellshock?

Tags: 14.04

To know if you are vulnerable, you can run:

```
env X="() { :;} ; echo busted" /bin/sh -c "echo completed"
env X="() { :;} ; echo busted" `which bash` -c "echo completed"
```

If you see "busted" then you are vulnerable.

Is there a patch yet?

Comment: 13.04 has been out of support for some time, so instead of patching, think about switching to a supported LTS release, 14.04 or 12.04.

Comment: It's a good suggestion and may be what I have to do - but I have a number of deployed systems on 13.04 and I expect stuff will break if I upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: @MikeMcKay if you are concerned about this bug in 13.04 why are you not concerned about not getting updates at all in 13.04?! "Is there a patch yet?" No, and there will most likely not be a patch for 13.04.

Comment: @Rinzwind I didn't realize that there were no security updates for 13.04 at all. That said, this bug is particularly easy to exploit - hence my concern. I guess I need to upgrade the distro.

Comment: The fix has been pushed already for the not EOL versions --- got mine this morning, few hours ago.

Comment: Anyway, still some problem to fix... look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146849/how-do-i-recompile-bash-to-avoid-the-remote-exploit-cve-2014-6271-and-cve-2014-7

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/528101/what-is-the-cve-2014-6271-bash-vulnerability-and-how-do-i-fix-it