# How to Patch for Shellshock

Tags: 14.04, bash, security, patch

So, in light of [this closed thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528233/how-do-i-patch-ubuntu-13-04-for-shellshock), and [this article](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/09/everything-you-need-to-know-about.html?m=1), how can we patch for the shellshock bug/exploit/vulnerability for currently supported Ubuntu versions? 13.10 and 14.04?

Comment: ***13.10 is not supported***. It's been end of life for months and will not have a patch released for it.

Comment: yah this woke me up to the fact that my OS for code development is EoL... so last weekend I bought a new SSD and loaded 14.04 onto it :)