# bash version does not change

Tags: bash

bash has been updated at least twice in the last two days, but the output of

```
bash --version
```

did not change. Its first line keeps saying:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. To verify that you're using a patched version of `bash`, test using the package management tools (or using the [sample test command](https://askubuntu.com/a/528102/158442)):

```
$ apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 4.3-7ubuntu1.3
  Candidate: 4.3-7ubuntu1.3
```

The `bash` version string remains unchanged as the patches were applied by the package maintainers, and not by upstream.