# No longer see Bash warning messages for Shellshock after update

Tags: updates, bash, software-center

I just updated Ubuntu from an Update pop-up.  I am aware of Shellshock, so I quickly went ahead with the install. Now, when I try running

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'echo hello'
```

I don't get the output (which I was getting before)

```
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
hello
```

as described in [What is the CVE-2014-6271 bash vulnerability (Shellshock) and how do I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528101/what-is-the-cve-2014-6271-bash-vulnerability-shellshock-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Rather, now I just get 'hello'.  Is it safe to assume the updates that I installed hides these error messages?  After reviewing the Software Center, I see the follwoing updates I installed:

```
unity-settings-daemon (14.04.0+14.04.20140414-0ubuntu1, 14.04.0+14.04.20140606-0ubuntu1
aptdaemon-data (1.1.1-1ubuntu5, 1.1.1-1ubuntu5.1)
python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (1.1.1-1ubuntu5, 1.1.1-1ubuntu5.1)
bash (4.3-7ubuntu1.3, 4.3-7ubuntu1.4)
python-aptdaemon (1.1.1-1ubuntu5, 1.1.1-1ubuntu5.1)
```

More specificly, does 4.3-7ubuntu1.4 hide the function definition attempt error message?  Sorry for the suspicion but after some Googling, I have yet to find a similar problem.  Any clarity will be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Fedora Magazine post](http://fedoramagazine.org/shellshock-how-does-it-actually-work/):

> ```
> env x='() { :;}; echo OOPS' bash -c :
> ```
>
> This will print “OOPS” on a vulnerable system, but exit silently if bash has been patched.

This is the behaviour seen on:

- Debian `squeeze` (`bash` package `4.1-3+deb6u2`)
- CentOS 6.5 (`bash` package `0:4.1.2-15.el6_5.2`)
- Arch Linux (`bash` package `4.3.026-1`)

I speculate that this is how the fix is intended to make it behave, but for some reason, Ubuntu's initial `bash` patches produced the error instead of ignoring the extra code silently.

---

[mattdm's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529260/no-longer-see-bash-warning-messages-for-shellshock-after-update/529295?noredirect=1#comment724786_529295):

> The initial patches were actually *intended* to produce the error when a bad function definition was found in an environment variable. The updated patches only even look in specially-prefixed variables, which eliminates all most all of the real-world risk. Try `env 'BASH_FUNC_x()'='() { :;}; echo OOPS' bash -c :` — you should see an error.

I have verified this:

```
$ env 'BASH_FUNC_x()'='() { :;}; echo OOPS' bash -c :
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `BASH_FUNC_x`
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ apt-cache policy bash | grep Installed
  Installed: 4.3-7ubuntu1.4
```

Comment: The initial patches were actually _intended_ to produce the error when a bad function definition was found in an environment variable. The updated patches only even look in specially-prefixed variables, which eliminates all most all of the real-world risk. Try `env 'BASH_FUNC_x()'='() { :;}; echo OOPS' bash -c :` — you should see an error.

Comment: (I'm assuming that Ubuntu is using the same patch we are; there might be a minor difference.)

Comment: @mattdm Thanks, you're correct! (Who's "we", btw?)

Comment: "We" in that context is Fedora.

Comment: @mattdm Ah, I didn't realize you were the author of the linked post. Great post, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. And an update: [the patch accepted upstream](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/bash43-027) now uses `%%` for the suffix instead of `()`, so it'll be `BASH_FUNC_x%%`