# Install only bash from trusty on old distributions (to be save from Shellshock vulnerability)

Tags: bash, pinning, shellshock, vulnerability

Is there a way to just install only bash from the latest distribution on an old mashine?

I once did pinning to a certain version of a package, but that was bevcause I didn't want to update that specific package. Here it would be pinning in the future.

Is this possible? Or is there a PPA I could add in these old repositories?

I don't want to just [patch the shellshock vulnerability](https://superuser.com/q/816787), I rather would like to add e repository, so I get frequent updates if there are more vulnerabilities found.

Comment: related: [How do I patch the shellshock vulnerability on an obsolete Ubuntu system that I can't upgrade?](http://superuser.com/q/816787)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't work on your old system installing just the `bash` Debian package from [security.ubuntu.com](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/):

- [Packages Ubuntu "bash"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bash)

try **applying all patches to bash** in a row by the script provided here:

[What is the CVE-2014-6271 bash vulnerability (Shellshock) and how do I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528101/what-is-the-cve-2014-6271-bash-vulnerability-shellshock-and-how-do-i-fix-it/528171#528171)

Answer (score 1):

The main reason we do not recommend running old unsupported releases is that they will not automatically get security fixes.

For bash releases 10.04 LTS, 12.04 LTS, and 14.04 LTS only will get a security update und upgrading.

Adding a random ppa to an old release may introduce even more severe security issues in case you do not know the maintainers of this ppa. In addition, many ppa will often also not offer packages for old unsupported releases.

However you can always downlaod and install any package from it's Debian package, which is available for download from official ressources. Only in case debendencies can not be resolved from a newer release to an old release we can not do so. For [bash](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/bash) it should be safe to download and install from a newer downloaded Debian package, as dependencies are the same in new, and older releases (but possibly not in very old releases).

From the link below select your release on top of the page (preselected for **trusty**), then select your architecture (**amd64** or **i386**) at the bottom of the page for downloading a Debian package of bash from [security.ubuntu.com](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/).

- [Packages Ubuntu "bash"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bash)