# restore patched bash to apt maintained

Tags: apt, bash, security

Last month I manually patched bash on a server running ubuntu 11.10 for the shellshock bug, as suggested in the comments here: [What is the CVE-2014-6271 bash vulnerability (Shellshock) and how do I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528101/what-is-the-cve-2014-6271-bash-vulnerability-shellshock-and-how-do-i-fix-it).  I've now done a release-upgrade to 12.04 which is supported. How should I uninstall the patch and restore bash to be apt maintained?

edit:

running `make uninstall` on the patch did the job, thanks @muru for the suggestion

Comment: If you did a do-release-upgrade, the manually patched version should have been overwritten. Are you sure it is still the one you added?

Comment: I was before your comment :-).  But now I can see that you are right - it has been overwritten.  To check this I wrote "echo $BASH_VERSION" into a terminal and I saw the /bin/bash version, not the /usr/local/bin/bash version.

Comment: So you installed it to /usr/local/ and made a symlink to /bin/bash, I suppose? Be careful. While `/bin/bash` will open the apt-installed version, just `bash` will open `/usr/local/bin/bash`, as `/usr/local/bin` has higher precedence in the PATH. I think you can try `make uninstall`, or other steps from http://stackoverflow.com/q/1439950/2072269

Comment: Actually, here's the thing: typing "which bash" into my terminal returns '/usr/local/bin/bash'.  This is what made me think I was still using the patched bash.

Comment: I take it that `echo $BASH_VERSION` has provided a false signal in this case. I'll have a look at `make uninstall` in my virtual machine testbed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `bash` is at the newest available version with:

```
[romano:~/etc] % apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 4.3-7ubuntu1.4
  Candidate: 4.3-7ubuntu1.4
  Version table:
 *** 4.3-7ubuntu1.4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.3-6ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

If not, you probably held(1) it; to unhold:

```
[romano:~/etc] % sudo apt-mark unhold bash
```

and then the normal `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade` should give you a completely up-to-date system.

BTW, to see a list of held packages, the incantation is:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

---

Footnotes:

(1) "Holding" a package means asking the package system to refuse to upgrade it to newer versions.

Comment: The installed version is the latest, I hadnt held it.  I was worried (perhaps unnecessarily it turns out) that bash was still routed to the patched version.