# Ubuntu 14.04 Vulnerable to Shellshock?

Tags: 14.04, shellshock

I just installed 14.04 today, found seems the system still have Shellshock issue:

```
dli@srv:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
dli@srv:~$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
vulnerable
this is a test
```

I think might be better to get it fixed from the installation image?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` yet?  The last time I checked with the Ubuntu Security Team there were no unfixed Shellshock issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen from [What is the CVE-2014-6271 bash vulnerability (Shellshock) and how do I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528101/what-is-the-cve-2014-6271-bash-vulnerability-shellshock-and-how-do-i-fix-it), the patched version for 14.04 is [`4.3-7ubuntu1.4`](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2364-1/), whereas the 14.04.1 image contains [`4.3-6ubuntu1`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.manifest). Once released, an ISO is never changed. So an installation image will contain the fix when 14.04.2 is released.

Comment: @dli note that a simple `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` will fix this on installed OSes - however as muru states the ISOs are not updated themselves, so only updating your system with `apt-get` or Update Manager (if GUI) will fix it on actual installs.

Comment: @ThomasW., yes, thank you very much also! I test your command works very well!